# NANO-X Microwindows Embedded Linux

Tags: embedded, arm, embedded-resource, embedded-linux

Hello I am new to the coding for the Embedded Linux for ARM platform.
I am using the NANO-X microwindopw for the GUI inteface for the Linux server, so i have downloaded the nano-x soruce from (ftp://microwindows.censoft.com/pub/microwindows/)
then i try to compile the demo code for the nano-x. when i try to compile it gives me the error 
: undefined reference to `GrOpen',' GrReqShmCmds'............... 
I could not successfully build it.

I have included all the header files from the /microwin/src/include/ to the /usr/include.

still i am getting the error.

Comment: I am compiling with the GCC compiler and I have added all the Header files from the Source directory to the usr/include on my system.

Comment: Please provide console output for the compilation. Also details on what compiler you were using and where you were compiling it (host or target) would be helpful.

Comment: I am using GCC compiler and i am compiling it on my host (LINUX PC)here is the screenshot.

Comment: prompt@prompt-desktop:/media/8CCC8E9BCC8E7F68/microwin/src/demos/nanox$ gcc demo.c
/tmp/cc8I4zDk.o: In function `main':
demo.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `GrOpen'
demo.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `GrReqShmCmds'
demo.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `GrGetScreenInfo'
demo.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `GrSetErrorHandler'
demo.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `GrNewWindow'
demo.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `GrNewWindow'
demo.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `GrNewWindow'
.............

Comment: I got it and i compiled all the Demos for the NANO-x GUI.....

Comment: I was not including all the libraries needed for the NANO-X functions.